# Rudin exercise problem 2.12

Tags: real-analysis

I hope I could get clarification on a solution to 2.12 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis.

> Let K $\subset$ $R^1$ consist of $0$ and the numbers $\frac{1}{n}$, for $n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$. Prove that K is compact directly from the definition (without using Heine-Borel theorem).

I found a solution online but I'm still stumbled. The solution is as follows:

> Let {$G_\alpha$} be an open cover of K. For n = 1, 2, ..., choose an index $\alpha_n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}$ $\in$ $G_{\alpha_n}$, and an index $\alpha_0$ such that 0 $\in$ $G_{\alpha_0}$. By definition of open sets, there exists r > 0 such that y $\in$ $G_{\alpha_0}$ whenever |y| = |y - 0| < r. Also, by Archimedean, there exists a positive number N such that $\frac{1}{N}$ < r. So we have $\frac{1}{n}$ $\in$ $G_{\alpha_0}$ for all n $\geq$ N (So far, what I understand here is that we are trying to construct an open set $G_{\alpha_0}$, enough to contain some $\frac{1}{n}$ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{N}$), and hence there is a finitely many subcollection { $G_{\alpha_0}$, $G_{\alpha_1}$, $G_{\alpha_2}$, ... , $G_{\alpha_{N-1}}$ } of {$G_\alpha$} that covers K. (Here, I could not figure out why the number of open sets stops at N - 1)

Note: the solution is from [artofproblemsolving](https://artofproblemsolving.com). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The $N$ is chosen to do more more than $G_{a_0}$ covering some $1/n$. It is chosen such that $G_{a_0}$ covers all $1/n\leq 1/N$. Note the "whenever" in "$y\in G_{a_0}$ whenever $|y|=|y-0|<r$". So, $G_{a_1},...,G_{a_{N-1}}$ will take care of covering $1/1,1/2,1/3,...1/(N-1)$ and $G_{a_0}$ will take care of covering all other $1/n$.

Comment: The idea here is that any open set containing $0$ must necessarily cover some tail of the sequence $\{\frac1n\}$, so only finitely many more open sets are needed to cover the finite number of points outside of that tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea here is that for any open set $U$ containing $0$, only a finite number of the points in $K$ can be outside of $U$. (This means $U$ must contain an infinite number of points in $K$.)

So the proof names $G_{\alpha_0}$ as a set which does contain $0$. Then it shows that there is an $N$ so that for **every** $n \geq N$ (not just "some $\frac{1}{n}$"), $\frac{1}{n} \in G_{\alpha_0}$. Then the remaining points are $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n<N$. There are a finite number of these, and each must be in at least one set, called $G_{\alpha_n}$. So taking $\{G_{\alpha_0}, G_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, G_{\alpha_{N-1}}\}$ includes all the points of $K$; it is a finite subcover of $K$. The sets $G_{\alpha_N}, G_{\alpha_{N+1}}, \ldots$ are not needed because $G_{\alpha_0}$ covers the rest of the $\frac{1}{n}$ points (in addition to $0$).

Comment: To be clear, I'd say that the key idea is that an open set containing $0$ must contain all but finitely many points of $K$.  That's a stronger requirement that saying that such a set must contain infinitely many points of $K$.

Comment: @RobertShore Yeah, maybe I should rephrase that first sentence, to make it clear that the second part is the important part and is NOT a conclusion from the first part.